# "Hold for Authentication" when printing through LP / LPR

Tags: macos, keychain, printing

I have a Dell network printer mapped to my MAC. 
I'm able to print from applications without any issues, but when I try to print using terminal (lp or lpr), every file gets held up on the printer with "Hold for authentication"

I'm able to enter my details for the printer and the job goes through, but I'm prompted every time I try to print using lp. Saving my details to the keychain does   not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before. Try the following to resolve it:

1. Send something to print so that you get the `Hold for authentication` error
2. In Terminal enter `lpstat -s`
3. From the output identify the printer name - it should be preceded by `device for` and followed by a colon `:` and a printer address. For example, if your output looked like:

`device for Brother_MFC_9335CDW: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-9335CDW._ipp._tcp.local.`

Then your printer name would be `Brother_MFC_9335CDW`

4. Now enter the following command:

`sudo lpadmin -p PrinterName -o auth-info-required=username,password`

**NOTE:** Replace the `PrinterName` with your printer's name from Step 3

5. You should be prompted for your Mac user password - enter this and press <kbd>return</kbd>
6. Now try printing again as a test.

If it doesn't work, let me know and we'll troubleshoot further.

---

Since the above didn't work we'll repeat the process with some minor adjustments. More specifically, **after** Step 1 but **before** Step 2, do the following:

- Open the Printer queue
- Click on the 'Refresh' icon (it's the circular one with an arrow)
- You should now get prompted for your credentials (i.e. username and password)

Now proceed with Step 2 from above.

Comment: Same issue, get the "Hold for authentication"

Comment: Ok, just to be thorough, you had the `Hold for authentication` error while you carried out steps 2 etc? I've added more to my answer, but if it doesn't work let me know as there's still more we can try.

Comment: Just following up on this. Did you get a resolution?

Comment: Hi, yes the steps in the update worked. Many thanks.

Comment: I have tried both variants (with adjustements and w/o) but neither of them worked for me (I still get "Hold for authentication" error). Can someone check if it is works also under macOS 11 (I am running 11.1)?